# Xorg high CPU use starting at boot in both Ubuntu 20.04 and Debian 11 running KDE in 2022

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, xorg, kde

I am booting to KDE and immediately Xorg uses a constant 40% of one CPU. This occurs on both Ubuntu 20.04 and Debian 11. This severely interferes with mouse usage causing it to lag and stutter mid-drag or highlight

There seem to be a lot of complaints on this issue, but little in the way of solutions other than to start “ripping wires out.” Particularly deafening is the silence from the KDE folks.

I am using the Nvidia 470 drivers (proprietary, tested) but the problem persists.

Here is a screenshot of Xorg CPU usage immediately after booting:

[image: Screenshot.]

Does anyone know what is causing it?
Or how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to use `top` .... I don't know exactly how to activate it before KDE...

Comment: Xorg takes 4% of the machine's cpu, that is 40% of a single CPU as shown above.  It is constant from boot in either Ubuntu 20.04 or Debian 11.

Comment: Does 4% really matters in 2022? Please reply by email to `basile@starynkevitch.net` (near Paris in France). Good night.

Comment: Please read the original post.  40% cpu for Xorg under KDE directly affects mouse usability, read:  whatever you are dragging is dropped, focus is lost, mouse does not make to where you want when you click, and the click is registered on an unwanted part of the screen.   The calendar year makes no difference.

Comment: Did you try Gnome or XFCE? Do they show the same behavior?

Comment: Yes, it occurs in Gnome on both Ubuntu 20.04 and Debian 11.   I do not use XFCE.

Answer (score 0):

With this last update in Nvidia video drivers, the problem "went away" in both Ubuntu 20.04 and Debian 11.

The update version under which the problem "went away":

Nvidia driver version:  510.47.03

Server vendor string:   The X.Org Foundation

Server vendor version:  1.20.13 (12013000)

NV-CONTROL verssion:    1.29